# Treat scala function with default parameter type as if it did not have default parameters

Tags: scala, types

Disclaimer: I'm new to Scala.

I want to pass a function with default parameters as if its type did not have default parameters

```
import scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3

type Record = Map[String, String]
type Dataset = Seq[Record]

def dropDuplicates(dataset: Dataset, keyF: Record => Any = recordHash) : Dataset = {
  // keep only distinct records as defined by the key function
  // removed method body for simplicity
  return dataset
}

def recordHash(record: Record, attributes: Option[Seq[String]] = None) : Int = {
  val values : Seq[String] = attributes
    .getOrElse(record.keys.toSeq.sorted)
    .map(attr => record(attr))
    return MurmurHash3.seqHash(values)
}
```

Here's the error I'm getting at compile time:

```
error: type mismatch;
[ant:scalac]  found   : (Record, Option[Seq[String]]) => Int
[ant:scalac]  required: Record => Any
[ant:scalac]   def dropDuplicates(dataset: Dataset, keyF: Record => Any = recordHash) : Dataset = {
```

Intuitively, I think of `recordHash` as type `Record => Int` when the default parameter `attributes` is not provided. Is there a way to treat `recordHash` as type `Record => Int`?

Comment: Keep in mind scala doesn't need an explicit `return`, the last statement of a function will be returned.

Comment: Yes implicit is preferred in Scala. I don't have much python experience so I wouldn't have guessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I can't compile your code because I miss some types, but</s> I think this will work.

```
def dropDuplicates(dataset: Dataset, keyF: Record => Any = recordHash(_)) : Dataset = {
  // keep only distinct records as defined by the key function
}
```

This works because `recordHash(_)` is equivalent to `x => recordHash(x)`, this way `x` (the input of the function) is `Record` which is the type you wanted.

Comment: What is the use of underscore in this context called? Can you provide a brief explanation of the intuition behind this or a link to some documentation on how underscore achieves this?